# Python: Data from excel into pie chart

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and have searched a lot on web regarding my issue but got nothing.

I have a file which has 3 columns:

```
Issue_id
Type
Status
```

Now I want to create a pie chart which will tell the status of all the issues we have in the excel sheet.

I have used the following code and getting the results but in the pie chart, I am only getting values not the status.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.axis('equal')

wb=pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')

a = wb.groupby('Status').Status.count()
print(type(a))
print(a)

ax.pie(a, labels=a, autopct='%1.1f%%')

#print(b)
plt.show()
```

Can anyone please let me know what am I lacking?

Excel :

[image: Excel]

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Can you provide an example data that reproduces your error?

Comment: just add  `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 0):

From my test, the issue is how you are passing the labels in:

```
ax.pie(a, labels=a, autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

You should instead pass the index of the count object to get the appropriate labels. By passing a to labels you are just passing the counts. Passing a.index explicitly passes the names you are counting by.

```
ax.pie(a, labels=a.index, autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

Answer (score 0):

using your code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
ax.axis('equal')
wb=pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
a = wb.groupby('Status').Status.count()
b = wb.Status.unique()
ax.pie(a, labels=b, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.show()
```

with the following data

> Issue_Name,Type,Status A,1,Active C,2,Resolved C,2,Resolved
>   B,2,Proposed B,2,Proposed B,2,Proposed

You should get this
[image: output]

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find the unique function anywhere, it looks like a simple solution but was hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

you are wrong on labels, you should use `a.keys()` to get the proper labels

```
fig1, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.pie(a, labels=a.keys(), autopct='%1.1f%%')
ax.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]